# R data.table Subgroup counts and weighted percent of group summary

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table

```
n = 100000

DT = data.table(customer_ID = 1:n,
                married = rbinom(n, 1, 0.4),
                coupon = rbinom(n, 1, 0.15))
```

I need to create a table that summarizes the total number of married and unmarried customers, number of customers using a coupon, by marital status subgroup and last column that computes the percentage of customers using coupons for each subgroup by marital status.

The output should look something like this.

```
   married Customers using Coupons Total Customers percent_usecoupon
1:       0                    9036           59790          15.11290
2:       1                    5943           40210          14.77991
```

My current code is very inefficient and I'm sure there's a better syntax using data.table but I can't seem to find it. I've reproduced my current code below:

```
coupon_marital = DT[coupon == TRUE, .N, by = married][order(-N)] #Count of coupon use by marital status
total_marital = DT[, .N, by = married] #Total count by marital status
setnames(total_marital, "N", "Count") #Rename N to Count
coupon_marital = merge(coupon_marital, total_marital) #Merge data.tables

coupon_marital[, percent_usecoupon := N/Count*100, by = married] #Compute percentage coupon use
setnames(coupon_marital, c("N", "Count"), c("Customers using Coupons", "Total Customers")) #Rename N to Count
rm(total_marital)

print(coupon_marital)
```

I can't use dplyr and need to use data.table only. I'm fairly new to data.table syntax and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Create data

```
set.seed(10)
n = 100000
DT = data.table(customer_ID = 1:n,
                married = rbinom(n, 1, 0.4),
                coupon = rbinom(n, 1, 0.15))
```

Summarise data

```
DT[, .(N.UseCoupon   = sum(coupon)
      ,N.Total       = .N
      ,Pct.UseCoupon = 100*mean(coupon)), 
   by = married]

#    married N.UseCoupon N.Total Pct.UseCoupon
# 1:       0        8975   60223      14.90294
# 2:       1        5904   39777      14.84275
```

Comment: Use of `mean` is intelligent. Not sure if other option with continuing the pipe with `[,.(N.UseCoupon, N.Total, Pct.UseCoupon = 100*N.UseCoupon/N.Total]` was efficient.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MKR Re efficiency, looking at `?GForce` I guess making the third column afterwards should be most efficient `DT[, .(s = sum(x), n = .N), by=g][, p := s/n*100]`